# Problem calculating this integral for a probability distribution function?

Tags: calculus, statistics

Okay so I need to show $$f(x)=\frac{1}{\pi (1+x^2)}$$ is a probability distribution function. Clearly it is greater than zero for all $x$ so what is remaining is to show $$\int^\infty_{-\infty}f(x)~dx=1$$

To do this I said $$\int^\infty_{-\infty}f(x)~dx=1=\int^\infty_{0}f(x)~dx+\int^0_{-\infty}f(x)~dx$$

which is equal to $$\frac{1}{\pi}\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} arctan(t)+\frac{1}{\pi}\lim_{t \rightarrow -\infty} arctan(s)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}=0$$ but this should be one but if it was a $+$ then my answer would make sense. Can anyone tell me where I have gone wrong?

Comment: The second term comes from the lower limit, so it's negative.

Comment: Got it thanks!!

Comment: Thanks got it now mate one more question just generally how would I evaluate this integral if it was not defined at zero? Would I pick another value to split the integral apart or couldn't I calculate it? Or could I do it in one go and say it's the limit as a tends to infinity of the integral between a and minus a? is that valid?

Answer (score 1):

You swapped the bounds of the second integral:

$$
\int^0_{-\infty}f(x)~dx = \lim_{t \to -\infty} (0 - \arctan t) = + \frac \pi 2
$$

Comment: Thanks got it now mate one more question just generally how would I evaluate this integral if it was not defined at zero? Would I pick another value to split the integral apart or couldn't I calculate it? Or could I do it in one go and say it's the limit as a tends to infinity of the integral between a and minus a? is that valid?

Comment: @RyanD: You can split anywhere you want, you'll always get the same result. If you know a priori that the integral *exists* then you can compute it as $\lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{-a}^a$. That is also valid if the function to be integrated is non-negative as in this case. *Generally*, you have to take the limits for the lower bound to minus infinity and the upper bound to infinity independently.

Comment: Great thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Your last line is wrong. It should be

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} arctan(t)-\frac{1}{\pi}\lim_{t \rightarrow -\infty} arctan(s)=\frac{1}{2}-\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)=1$$

This is because the $-\infty$ in the second integral is the *lower* limit, so you take the value at zero minus the value at $-\infty$.

Comment: @Martin R Thanks got it now mate one more question just generally how would I evaluate this integral if it was not defined at zero? Would I pick another value to split the integral apart or couldn't I calculate it? Or could I do it in one go and say it's the limit as a tends to infinity of the integral between a and minus a? is that valid?

Comment: @MartinR, in his comment to his answer, said what I would have said.